# How to stem a pandas dataframe using nltk ? The output should be a stemmed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, stemming

I'm trying to pre-process a dataset. The dataset contains text data. I have created a pandas DataFrame from that dataset. 
my question is, how can I use stemming on the DataFrame and get a stemmed DataFrame as output?

Comment: What have you tried? What does a "stemmed data frame" means? You can steam a *word* using `nltk`, using a stemmer such as PorterStemmer or similar. But you likely want to split your text into words (or, actually, *tokens*) first and then stemmize the tokens. Try something on your own and then come back with a more solid question.. this question is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a certain pandas df you can stem the contents by applying a stemming function on the whole df after tokenizing the words.

For this, I exemplarily used the snowball stemmer from nltk.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
englishStemmer=SnowballStemmer("english") #define stemming dict
```

And this tokenizer:

```
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer as w_tokenizer
```

Define your function:

```
def stemm_texts(text):
    return [englishStemmer.stem(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(str(text))]
```

Apply the function on your df:

```
df = df.apply(lambda y: y.map(stemm_texts, na_action='ignore'))
```

Note that I additionally added the NaN ignore part.

You might want to detokenize again:

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer

detokenizer = TreebankWordDetokenizer()
df = df.apply(lambda y: y.map(detokenizer.detokenize, na_action='ignore'))
```